# Converting from binary to text in python

Tags: python, dataframe, binary

I have 10 `.npy` files and I tried to convert them into a text format . Eventually I could convert but inside of the file I have a lot of NaN as you can see below

```
'6273e+01,7.875215274794027209e+01,7.409557690727524459e+01,6.936124983476474881e+01,6.453527330490760505e+01,5.960374909394886345e+01,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,'
```

How can I remove NaN from the converted file, in other words, how can I convert `.npy` to csv or txt without problem?

Comment: Isn't it already in csv? have you checked whether the .npy files have NaN?

Comment: @skott not really, since the code doesn't work properly. I've tried the way which has been implied below but still, I have aforementioned problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.npy` is the extension used by numpy. Which means the file was likely created with [numpy.save()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html). So you can load the file and obtain the numpy array with [numpy.load()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html)

Once you have obtained your numpy array using numpy.load, you can then drop the NaN as follows:

```py
X = X[~np.isnan(X)]
```

The `~` operator negates the boolean-values returned by [np.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), and the boolean-values are then used to select the elements of the array. True values keep the respective element and False values drop the respective element.

Finally, you can export a numpy array `X` to a csv file using [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) as follows:

```py
np.savetxt('my-values.csv', [X], delimiter=',')
```

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.load('my-values.npy')
X = X[~np.isnan(X)]
np.savetxt('my-values.csv', [X], delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I tried using this code and it was useful. I could change it into csv